# JSONObject and JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

first i don't speak english well, please understand.

I use JAVA and 'bus arrive system API', but I have a problem.

if there is only one bus that will arrive, "item" is a JSONObject.

[image]

but if there are over 2 bus that will arrive, "item" is a JSONArray.
[image]

anyway I don't have any idea... if there are any ideas, please help me..
Thank you.

Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    no1.setText(""); no2.setText(""); no3.setText(""); no4.setText(""); no5.setText(""); no6.setText(""); no7.setText(""); no8.setText("");
    info1.setText(""); info2.setText(""); info3.setText(""); info4.setText(""); info5.setText("");  info6.setText("");  info7.setText("");  info8.setText("");  
    station1.setText(""); station2.setText(""); station3.setText(""); station4.setText(""); station5.setText(""); station6.setText(""); station7.setText(""); station8.setText(""); 
    time1.setText(""); time2.setText(""); time3.setText(""); time4.setText(""); time5.setText(""); time6.setText(""); time7.setText(""); time8.setText("");
}

private ArrayList<String> arrstation = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> arrtime = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> busno = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> businfo = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> intarrtime = new ArrayList<>();

public void Bus(){
    try{

        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("http://openapi.tago.go.kr/openapi/service/ArvlInfoInqireService/getSttnAcctoArvlPrearngeInfoList"); /*URL*/
        urlBuilder.append("?" + URLEncoder.encode("ServiceKey","UTF-8") + "=Tcit3Up%2FxLhDOivx1nH8pb9%2FJB1g44Wy7OC1pISvRlUCt2fnnPJyD0si1jFkvjlYXaixwMD%2BVV5j76M8i%2BEpuA%3D%3D"); /*Service Key*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("cityCode","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("32010", "UTF-8")); /*도시코드*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("nodeId","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("CCB250001349", "UTF-8")); /*정류소ID*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("_type", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("json", "UTF-8"));
        URL url = new URL(urlBuilder.toString());
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        System.out.println("Response code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        BufferedReader rd;
        if(conn.getResponseCode() >= 200 && conn.getResponseCode() <= 300) {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        } else {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
        }
        String result = new String();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result=result.concat(line);
        }
        System.out.println(result);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(result);
        System.out.println("parsing start");

        JSONObject response = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("response");

        JSONObject body = (JSONObject) response.get("body");

        JSONObject items = (JSONObject) body.get("items");

        JSONArray itemArray = (JSONArray) items.get("item");


        JSONObject item_array[] = new JSONObject[10];


        for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){
            item_array[i] = (JSONObject) itemArray.get(i);

            busno.add(item_array[i].get("routeno").toString());

            businfo.add(item_array[i].get("routetp").toString());
            arrtime.add(item_array[i].get("arrtime").toString());
            arrstation.add(item_array[i].get("arrprevstationcnt").toString());
            intarrtime.add(Integer.parseInt(arrtime.get(i))/60);
        }

        rd.close();
        conn.disconnect();


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    }

public void setBusLabel(ArrayList<String> busno, ArrayList<String> businfo, ArrayList<Integer> intarrtime, ArrayList<String> arrstation) {
    no1.setText(busno.get(0)); no2.setText(busno.get(1)); no3.setText(busno.get(2)); no4.setText(busno.get(3)); no5.setText(busno.get(4)); no6.setText(busno.get(5)); no7.setText(busno.get(6)); no8.setText(busno.get(7));
    info1.setText(businfo.get(0)); info2.setText(businfo.get(1)); info3.setText(businfo.get(2)); info4.setText(businfo.get(3)); info5.setText(businfo.get(4));  info6.setText(businfo.get(5));  info7.setText(businfo.get(6));  info8.setText(businfo.get(7));  
    /*
    time1.setText(intarrtime[0].toString()+"분"); time2.setText(intarrtime[1].toString()+"분"); time3.setText(intarrtime[2].toString()+"분"); time4.setText(intarrtime[3].toString()+"분"); time5.setText(intarrtime[4].toString()+"분"); time6.setText(intarrtime[5].toString()+"분"); time7.setText(intarrtime[6].toString()+"분"); time8.setText(intarrtime[7].toString()+"분");
    station1.setText(arrstation[0]); station2.setText(arrstation[1]); station3.setText(arrstation[2]); station4.setText(arrstation[3]); station5.setText(arrstation[4]); station6.setText(arrstation[5]);   station7.setText(arrstation[6]); station8.setText(arrstation[7] 
    */
}

public ArrayList<String> getArrstation() {
    return arrstation;
}

public void setArrstation1(ArrayList<String> arrstation) {
    this.arrstation = arrstation;
}

public ArrayList<String> getBusno() {
    return busno;
}

public void setBusno1(ArrayList<String> busno) {
    this.busno = busno;
}

public ArrayList<String> getBusinfo() {
    return businfo;
}

public void setBusinfo1(ArrayList<String> businfo) {
    this.businfo = businfo;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getIntarrtime() {
    return intarrtime;
}

public void setIntarrtime(ArrayList<Integer> intarrtime) {
    this.intarrtime = intarrtime;
}   

}
```

Comment: Well, you can always check via `instanceof`, e.g. `Object itemObj =  items.get("item"); if( itemObj instanceof JSONObject ) { ... }`. However, I personally wouldn't design that api in such an awkward way, i.e. I'd probably always use an array/list, even if it contains only one element.

Answer (score 1):

Though there is probably a design flaw in the service, you could just use *instanceOf*:

```
Object obj = items.get("item");

if( obj instanceOf JSONArray )
{

   //treat as JSONArray
}
else if(obj instanceOf JSONObject)
{

   //treat as JSONObject
}
```